# Configure Rails Carrierwave::Uploader with Aspose to display thumbnails of office docs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, aspose, cloudinary

Despite the well-documented Cloudinary API, I failed to use office docs Aspose conversion in my CarrierWave::Uploader. Here is my best shot:

```
class CamplogPicUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  cloudinary_transformation :resource_type=>:raw do
    process raw_convert: 'aspose'
  end
end
```

Office documents are well uploaded to Cloudinary but no associated pdf created as well.
Anybody can help?

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload an office files and convert it using Aspose you can use the following:

```
cloudinary_transformation resource_type: "raw", raw_convert: "aspose"
```

To access the pdf you can use:

```
pic.url(resource_type: "image", format: "#{pic.format}.pdf")
```